# Get every day of the current week

Tags: php, date

I need to get every day of the current week.

Here is what I have done so far, it seems to work but I want to know if I can do it better.

```
$weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
$days = [];
foreach($weekdays as $k => $v){
    $days[$k] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(''.$v.' 0 week'));
}
```

Comment: Get the date of Monday of this week, then just add 1 through 6 days to get the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example using the **\DateTime** object and the [modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method:

```
<?php
$days = [];
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->modify('this week monday');
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $days[$i] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
```

In the code we set the date object to the current week's monday and then cycle it 7 times by shifting the date to next day on each iteration.

The complete list of supported formats for [DateTime::modify is here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Comment: Thanks!, I was trying to do something similar with a for loop but this works much better

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the array with the days of the week.

```
$days = [];
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $days[$i] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("Monday this week +$i days"));
}
```

The same with DateTime:

```
$days = [];
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $days[$i] = date_create("Monday this week +$i days")->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: Thank you I like this a lot more than what I had. I ended up getting Monday of next week with my code which was not my goal.